# VS Code Go intellisense causing problems

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, intellisense

`fmt.Printf("hello")` was working great with intellisense
[image]

but suddenly in every go file my `fmt.P ..` suggestion becomes this
[image]

and this
[image]

I am not getting "fmt.Printf()" suggestions anymore and getting stuck with those "const", "func", "import", "type", & "var".. what is happening? (Though it is not suggesting `fmt.Printf()` but it's still working). how can I get normal suggestions by intellisense like previous?

I tried disabling GO official extension, then it got fixed but also I lose all autocomplete/suggestion feature. a go file in root directory is working fine but other files inside packages are showing this kinda problems. Please help

Comment: Is the file detected as a GO source code? You can see it on the bottom right corner

Comment: yeah, i can even call function from here. functionality is working but intellisense is not

Comment: Looks like the language server crashed. Restart the server or reload the window. To restart the server: press "Ctrl-Shift-P" and type "Restart language server" in the popup and press "Enter". To reload window:  press "Ctrl-Shift-P" and type "Reload Window". It will restat the language server as well.

Comment: tried and didn't fix that

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I couldn't find exact problem and solution. And somehow I saw some were facing **"case-insensitive import collision:"** and it was due to upper-case and lower-case mixture usage in filename. I remembered it seeing in my package name (though this error vanishes sometimes and ignored it as code execution was working) and tried renaming my filename from "sequenceUtils.go" to "sequence_utils.go" and boom ..! intellisense started working ..! though my colleague was working with same filename and he wasn't facing problems..

I think the problem should be properly identified..!

Comment: Wasn't there already diagnostics? Usually when such things happen, gopls shows diagnostics (PROBLEMS tab) or, a hanging progress notification (at the bottom of the window).

Comment: no, there wasn't a single indication of the actual problem